# How to Merge/Override values in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have below values in values.yaml file

```
spec:
  teamId: "postgres"
  volume:
    size: 1Gi
  numberOfInstances: 1
  users:  # Application/Robot users
    a3s:
    - superuser
 tls:
    secretName: ""
```

I would like to override the secretName to {{ .Release.Name }} when some condition is met and print the values.yaml file with {{ .Release.Name }} else it should print as it is 
Any suggestion please ?

Comment: you can use conditional block on secret `metadata:name`. Is there any use case on overriding only in values.yaml file?

Comment: If you run `helm create` and look at the generated `templates/_helpers.tpl`, you'll see some Go templates that basically implement this logic.  I'd replicate that path.

Answer (score 1):

In values.yaml

```
tls:
  secretName: "{{ if condition_check_here }} {{.Release.Name}} {{else }} othervalue {{end}}"
```

where the `tls.secretName` will be used, use like following

```
{{tpl .Values.tls.secretName . }}
```